# Curly Braces when Extending Node.js Class

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Why do we wrap our variables in curly braces, like `{EventEmitter} = require 'events'`, when extending a Node.js class?

For example, Trevor Burnham, in his [tutorial](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2011-08/decouple-your-apps-with-eventdriven-coffeescript) on Event-Driven CoffeeScript, extends Node's EventEmitter this way:

```
{EventEmitter} = require 'events'

class Rooster extends EventEmitter
  constructor: ->
    @on 'wake', -> console.log 'COCKADOODLEDOO!'

(foghorn = new Rooster).emit 'wake' # COCKADOODLEDOO!
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This:

```
{EventEmitter} = require 'events'
```

is equivalent to this JavaScript:

```
var EventEmitter;
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
```

When you `require 'events'`, you're getting an object back with the module's exports, one of those exports is the `EventEmitter` "class". Using `{EventEmitter}` is just an idiomatic shortcut for pulling `EventEmitter` out of the object that `require 'events'` returns; you could also say this:

```
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
```

if you prefer. The braced version starts to come in handy when you want to extract more than one part of an object; for example, this:

```
{a, b} = c
```

is like this JavaScript:

```
var a, b;
a = c.a;
b = c.b;
```

The [Destructuring Assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) section of the CoffeeScript documentation might make some good reading right about now.